# Building UI to connect to API

Tags: angular, reactjs, pagination

I need to build a UI that connects to an API.  The API is built in .NET core and the data set is about 800 items.  Each item is a complex object.

I would like to build an SPA that returns let's say 50 rows at a time from the API, with a click through to the details view.

I'm not sure whether Angular or React would be better for this, or whether it even makes a difference.  I've worked in Angular in the past but would be open to working in React.  I've heard that React is a bit easier to work with.

I'm looking for some general pointing in the right direction, or even if anyone knows of existing github projects that will do the trick.  Also... am I overthinking this?  The dataset is about 800kb.  I'm thinking I shouldn't just download it all at once.

Comment: Is this API serving static data or does the data change? Preloading 800kb is a possibility if its static.

Comment: It will change on a daily basis, but not constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is every day stuff. Making API calls to retrieve data. No biggie there. Both Angular and React offer store based solutions for caching if required. Angular alternatively, also offers the simplicity of services.

Routing for the click through, both libs are very advanced in this area and work in almost identical ways.

React, you rarely need to refer to the docs but its open to abuse. Angular is more structured and I love the separation of the view into a natural feeling HTML file.

In terms of downloading it all at once, you could preload it all. Then your app would fly. 800kb should not take long. But if your data changes at the backend regularly then you'll need to keep fetching the data to make sure you are up to date which kind of negates the advantage of pre-loading. However, it does give you a cache to work from whilst you are waiting for new data.

In general, I don't think it matters either way which tech you use. They are both fully featured and will do the job with ease. (But my biased advice is stick with Angular :))

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer!